# Mpmath hypergeometric function shows different behaviour for high & low precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpmath

For one of my projects, I need to repeatedly evaluate an expression involving the general hypergeometric function. While SciPy does not support the general HypGeo function, MPMath does. However, using `mp.hyper(..)` is very time consuming. So instead I decided to use their fast precision library function `fp.hyper(..)`. Unfortunately the behaviour seems to be completely different. My example below:

```
from mpmath import mp, fp
from math import sin, cos, pi

H = 0.2
k = 2

A = 4 * sqrt(H) / (1 + 2 * H)
B = 4 * pi / (3 + 2 * H)
C = H/2 + 3/4


f_high = lambda t: (B * k * t * sin(pi * k) *
                   mp.hyper([1], [C+1/2, C+1], -(k*pi*t)**2) +
                   cos(pi * k) * mp.hyper([1], [C, C + 1/2],
                   -(k*pi*t)**2)) * A * t**(H + 1/2)


f_low = lambda t: (B * k * t * sin(pi * k) *
                   fp.hyper([1], [C+1/2, C+1], -(k*pi*t)**2) +
                   cos(pi * k) * fp.hyper([1], [C, C + 1/2],
                   -(k*pi*t)**2)) * A * t**(H + 1/2)
```

[image: Obtained using fp.plot(f_high,[0,5]

[image: Obtained through fp.plot(f_low,[0,5]

The first plot shows `fp.plot(f_high,[0,1])`, the second one `fp.plot(f_low,[0,1])`. In case anyone is wondering: The functions look ugly but one is a copy of the other, just `mp` replaced by `fp`, so there is no chance they differ in any other way.

I also plotted it in Mathematica and the picture is more like the upper one (high precision).

Looks like there is a mistake with the implementation of the `fp.hyper` function, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/contexts.html#fast-low-precision-arithmetic-fp) for `fp` says (emphasis added):

> Due to intermediate rounding and cancellation errors, results computed with fp arithmetic may be much less accurate than those computed with mp using an equivalent precision (mp.prec = 53), since the latter often uses increased internal precision. The accuracy is highly problem-dependent: for some functions, fp almost always gives 14-15 correct digits; for others, results can be accurate to only 2-3 digits **or even completely wrong**.  The recommended use for fp is therefore to speed up large-scale computations where accuracy can be verified in advance on a subset of the input set, or where results can be verified afterwards.

If `fp` were just a drop-in replacement for `mp` with faster computation and no downside, there would be no reason for `mp` to exist.  In this case, it appears that `fp` is not suited for your task, so you'll have to use `mp`.

Comment: Of course it is clear that there is a tradeoff between precision and computation time but the fp.implementation shows a completely different behaviour?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you except what the documentation already says.  Note where it says "or even completely wrong".  Presumably there is a loss of precision at some crucial point in your computation that results in "completely wrong" results.

Comment: @sbm: There is a tradeoff. You have traded away essentially *all* of your precision. You were warned that this could happen.